# MPMoviePlayer stops playing going in background

Tags: ios

need to play audio in background with MpMoviePlayerController. I know that I have to use this code to achieve that:

```
  AVAudioSession *audioSession = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
  [audioSession setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:nil];
   [audioSession setActive:YES error:nil];
```

and set the "RequireBakgroundMode" in the pList.

This is working fine except for that when I put my app in background the sound stops and I have to open control center and press play to resume playback.

So my question is, how can I avoid the sound stopping when the app goes in background? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Set of Capabilities of you project.its working fine when apps enter in Background.

[image]

When you make enable mode then in plist file set background mode automatically.

[image]

Comment: sorry it is not working for me. Am I missing something? Are you sure the player keeps playing after you hit home button?

Comment: yes it working for me and this is only on way to play song in background. No one other way. your code missing something. remove from plist file "Required Backgound mode" and after add capability.

Comment: - (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    if([[UIApplication sharedApplication]  respondsToSelector:@selector(beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents)])
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents];
    // allows you to play in the background when app is suspended in iOS5
    [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setDelegate: self];
    [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory: AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:nil]; // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
   
}

Comment: -(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [self play];
}
-(void)play
{
    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"big_buck_bunny" ofType:@"mp4"]];
    self.moviePlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:url];
    [self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:self.moviePlayer];
    
}